# Choosing architecture for Winforms C# application

Tags: c#, architecture, architectural-patterns, winforms

I'm developing GUI for controlling and testing hardware device.

The GUI consists of many basic controls like textboxes and radio buttons which are mostly independent of each other - each control sends a command to device to read or write a parameter. And a couple of timer-based monitors querying the device for status every couple of seconds.

It was initially written as a WinForms application without any separation between view, data and communication layers.

There are no performance/scalability requirements. I'm looking for a better way to build something open for future modification for similar devices.

Which architectural pattern would be recommended for re-organizing such an application?

Edit: adding to helb's answer, I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) helpful in explaining different GUI architectures.

Comment: Regardless of my answer, you should make clear whether you are *rewriting* or *refactoring*.

Comment: You should say what the problems are with the current architecture, or what the goals are for the new architecture. Architecture is an answer to requirements.

Comment: @Martin The problem with the current architecture is the lack of any. I very little experience in GUI development but even for me it clearly looks like it will be very difficult to re-use the code in the future projects or even navigate and review in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are free to rewrite the entire software from scratch. I will assume so because you are asking for an architectural choice and not for refactoring tips.

**Choose the architectutre which matches the problem best.**

Start with the user needs, functional requirements and non-functional requirements. Especially non-functional requirements such as quality attributes (usability, maintainability, performance, scalability, etc.) play an important role when defining an architecture.

Only if all options are considered, a good architecture can result. Maybe your WinForms application should better be a web application hosted on the hardware itself or a set of automated tests. Just keep an open mind.

If, after careful consideration, you still conclude that an application with GUI is the best solution, consider refactoring the existing application with a strict MVC pattern in place or rewrite the application as a WPF application using a strict MVVM pattern.

Comment: Creating a webapp to test a hardware device seems both convoluted and excessive. I can't see a usecase where doing so would be easier than using a structure that can touch down with the OS without the hurdles imposed by such an architecture. Still, your answer is good overall - one needs first to understand the problem to then be able to work on the solution.

Comment: @T.Sar Depending on the type of hardware, it may make sense to integrate a maintenance page in the existing web interface.

Comment: Sure - up until you can't communicate with the hardware for some reason, and then can't access the maintenance page anymore to know what is going on. Putting the debug thing on the hardware you have to debug is akin to a "No keyboard found. Press F1 to continue" situation.

Comment: @T.Sar Good point ;-) But as said, it depends on the requirements.